# Class theory of ZF-minus-Powerset as classical predicative system?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

I've been thinking about some mathematics in weaker foundational systems a little bit, largely from a structural viewpoint, and with particular attention to classes.

Some categories I've been keeping in mind are:

- A category of classes, the information of which classes are sets, and how these behave in [Algebraic Set Theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+set+theory)
- The category of classes and class functions of [$\text{NBG}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory).
- The syntactic category of $\text{ZF}$ (Maschio, *What is the real category of sets?* arXiv:[1212.3107](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3107)), whose objects are first-order formulas of $\text{ZF}$ and whose morphisms are equivalence classes of formulas that describe class functions.

Some theories I've been keeping in mind are:

- Those in the approach of Awodey–Buss–Simpson–Streicher (*Relating first-order set theories, toposes and categories of classes*, Annals of Pure and Applied Logic **165** (2014) 428–502 doi:[10.1016/j.apal.2013.06.004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2013.06.004), [pdf](http://www.phil.cmu.edu/projects/ast/Papers/Awodey-Butz-Simpson-Streicher-APAL-2013.pdf)), where the axioms are broken down into stages so that weaker subsystems of the complete package can be meaningfully studied. (The "basic class structure" there asks that every class $X$ has a class of subsets $Y$, and allows that $X$ can be a set but $Y$ is not.)
- The predicative and constructive set theory [$\text{CZF}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/axioms-CZF-IZF.html), which has proper classes. (This is of limited use, since I'm only concerned with the case of classical logic today, and $\text{CZF}$ with classical logic is the same as $\text{ZF}$.)
- The theory $\text{CZF}_{\mathrm{Exp}}$, which has a model where the Dedekind reals form a proper class (Lubarsky–Rathjen, *On the Constructive Dedekind Reals*, Proceedings of LFCS 2007 (Lecture Notes in Computer Science **4514**), doi:[10.1007/s11813-007-0005-6](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11813-007-0005-6), arXiv:[1510.00641](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00641)).

**Q1. What would a reasonable classical, choice-free, predicative foundation be?**

A natural first candidate is $\text{ZF}-$, $\text{ZF}$ minus Powerset, or the analogue for $\text{NBG}$. I'm not fussed about classes not being objects in the former, since I'm happy to consider first-order formulas as syntactic entities that I can manipulate.

However, the analogous theory of $\text{ZFC}-$, where we just drop Powerset from the axioms, turned out to be a bit weaker than commonly assumed (Gitman–Hamkins–Johnstone, *What is the theory ZFC without power set?*, Math. Logic Q. **62** iss. 4–5 (2016) pp. 391-406, doi:[10.1002/malq.201500019](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.201500019), arXiv:[1110.2430](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2430)). The authors of that paper contend that "these deficits of $\text{ZFC}-$ are completely repaired by strengthening it to the theory $\text{ZFC}^-$, obtained by using collection rather than replacement."

So perhaps a better candidate for consideration is $\text{ZF}-$, but with Collection rather than Replacement, in addition to dropping Powerset from the standard axioms.

**Q2. Does this theory, $\text{ZF}$ minus Powerset with Collection instead of Replacement, need further modifications to be well-behaved?**

A similar question also holds for $\text{NBG}-$. One might reasonably demand that the 'basic class structure' holds for the category of classes in either theory, if one is thinking in that mode. Specifically, one should have a reasonable small powerclass: a class of all subsets of a given class, that interacts well with 'small class relations' in the usual way (similar to how relations from $x$ to $y$ can be classified by functions from $x$ to $P(y)$).

**Q3. Are there interesting or well-known models of $\text{ZF}$ minus Powerset with Collection instead of Replacement, in the way that $H_\kappa$ (for $\kappa$ regular and uncountable) is a model of $\text{ZFC}^-$?**

Solovay considered something similar in his paper *Hyperarithmetically encodable sets*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **239** (1978) 99–122, doi:[10.2307/1997849](https://doi.org/10.2307/1997849). However, similar to how Gitman–Hamkins–Johnstone note that the literature is sloppy about specifying $\text{ZFC}-$ vs $\text{ZFC}^-$, it's not clear what exactly $\text{ZF}^-$ is in Solovay's paper.

Comment: I think $\text{ZF}^-$ is an ok set theory, for the purposes of set theory. I think forcing theory works out ok. Los's Theorem is not provable since it's not provable in ZF. It's not clear exactly what would constitute an answer to the first question, though. What do you need $\text{ZF}^-$ to do? I can tell you which of the results in G-H-J go through in $\text{ZF}^-$, but it seems these are largely unrelated to your main interest (category theory, I assume).

Comment: Also I don't think that the predicativists would agree that $\text{ZF}^-$ is predicative, but I'm probably not the right person to judge.

Comment: I guess it's relevant that one can't prove in ZF that $\text{ZF}^-$ holds in $H(\kappa)$ for $\kappa$ regular uncountable, even though one can show $\text{ZF-}$ does hold. (Sadly, this problem arises in my current research...)

Comment: @Gabe ok, it's really modulo the usual differences between ZFC and ZF. Maybe the biggest thing I don't know is whether we get any rank-type function on the class of all sets, since clearly we don't have the power set available!

Comment: @Gabe: What's $H(\kappa)$ in ZF? I know of several competing definitions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I just meant the union of all transitive sets that are the surjective image of a cardinal less than $\kappa$. I guess this is actually a model of $\text{ZFC-}$, right?

Comment: @DavidRoberts The recursion theorem is provable without the powerset axiom, so you can define $\text{rank}(x) = \sup_{u\in x} \text{rank}(u) + 1$. I think Kunen actually makes a point of this in the second edition of his textbook.

Comment: @Gabe ok, that's cool. Though, does this stratify V by sets? As in, is V_alpha still a set?

Comment: @Gabe: With David Aspero we defined $H(\kappa)$ as the union of all transitive sets which do not map onto $\kappa$. And that *will* stratify $V$ (although you may need to add limits "by hand").

Comment: @AsafKaragila But then you can't prove $H(\kappa)$ is a set, right?

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, we can. Every transitive set can be mapped onto its rank. So a transitive set which cannot be mapped onto $\kappa$ must be in $V_\kappa$. (Surprisingly, we did not find that sort of statement in any of the usual set theory books. It wasn't a particularly clever or difficult proof, of course.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh of course, nice. But I think David was asking about the rank function stratifying $V$ by sets in the context of $\text{ZF}^-$. The answer there is no (and your $H(\kappa)$ won't work either)

Comment: @DavidRoberts If we let $V_\alpha$ as a collection of all sets of rank less than $\alpha$, and if every $V_\alpha$ is a set, then the axiom of power set holds.

Comment: (Side note: I think we may define $V_\alpha$ as a successive application of powerclass operations, which is possible over CZF without subset collection. Of course, we cannot ensure $V_\alpha$ is a set without the powerset axiom, I do not know this is doable without any form of Collection, however.)

Comment: @Hanul ok, interesting. I'm not wedded to the $V_\alpha$ stratification, though.

Comment: @Asaf I'd be happy with any stratification by sets, I'm just not so familiar with the H hierarchy. But Gabe seems to think that won't work either, it seems.

Comment: I found the question intriguing but hard to read, so I revised it. I'm happy for you to edit if I introduced any errors, or to revert if this version isn't faithful to your ideas.

Comment: The results in my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05204v2 show that the category of sets in ZF$^-$ is a constructively well-pointed Boolean pretopos satisfying the structural separation and collection axioms.  This seems pretty good, except that it's not clear to me that it has a NNO.  In the absence of powersets or even function sets, can you define *parametrized* functions by recursion on $\omega$?

Comment: @MikeShulman Do you just need to know that for any set $A$, any $a\in A$, and any $f : A\to A$, there is a function $g :\omega\to A$ such that $g(0) = a$ and $g(n+1) = f(g(n))$ for all $n < \omega$? This much is provable in $\text{ZF}^-$, I think.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg We need to know that for any sets $S$ and $A$, any $a:S\to A$, and any $f:S\times A \to A$, there is a function $g:S\times \omega\to A$ such that $g(s,0) = a(s)$ and $g(s,n+1) = f(s,g(s,n))$ for all $n<\omega$.  (This is why I stressed *parametrized*.)

Comment: @MikeShulman That still seems OK to me using the usual recursion theorem, but maybe I'm missing something: define $g(s,n) = b$ if there is a sequence $\langle a_m\rangle_{m \leq n}$ with $a_0 = a(s)$, $a_n = b$, and $a_{m+1} = f(s,a_m)$ for all $m < n$, then use replacement of $S\times A$ to get that $g$ exists as a set. By the way, is the definition of an NNO on Wikipedia wrong? It doesn't look parameterized.

Comment: @Mike I would of course be happy to throw in what amounts to a parameterised NNO.

Comment: @Gabe when one is working in a cartesian closed category (for instance a topos), then the 'normal', unparametrised version of an NNO automatically satisfied the stronger universal property with parameters.

Comment: @Gabe oh, I see now: even the parametrised version further down is different. I believe Mike's version should be the right one. I don't know what goes wrong if only the one on WP is used.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg That seems plausible.  I hadn't thought about whether one can do it with replacement.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Do you mean the one at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers_object#Equivalent_definitions?  Yes, that seems different, only the zero is parametrized.  I wonder where WP got it from; maybe someone should fix it.

Comment: @MikeShulman yes. Though I've seen the one mentioned there before, in the literature, and wondered at it. I agree what you write is better.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Can you remember where in the literature?

Comment: @MikeShulman definition 2.1 in http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/24/3/24-03abs.html for instance.

Comment: @MikeShulman even more: Exercise 4 after section 0.9 (page 71) in Lambek and Scott's 1988 book _Introduction to Higher-Order Categorical Logic_ asks to prove that the usual NNO in a CCC can be expressed only using products in the "wrong" version. It may be people assumed this was enough when only products are available. Also Cockett's 1990 'Locoi' paper.

Comment: @DavidRoberts And even Remark A2.5.3 in the Elephant!  But now I think I see why this definition is actually equivalent: In the general case, given $S\to A$ and $S\times A\to A$, you can take $A'=S\times A$ and get $S\to A'$ and $A'\to A'$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Re: "I'd be happy with any stratification by sets, I'm just not so familiar with the H hierarchy. But Gabe seems to think that won't work either, it seems."

Here's a short argument that in general there isn't such a stratification. Assume $AC + \neg CH$ and consider the collection of hereditarily countable sets. This gives you a model of $ZFC^-$. No class over this model can be an Ord (= $\omega_1$) sequence of sets whose union is the whole model. Else, $\mathbb R$ would be the union of an $\omega_1$ sequence of countable sets, contradicting $\neg CH$.

Comment: @KamerynWilliams oh, thanks!

Comment: I don't think ZF− can be considered predicative by any stretch of the term. After all, the biggest impredicativity in ZFC is *unbounded* replacement, followed by unbounded comprehension, not really powerset. One can argue that if we restrict to bounded replacement and comprehension, then the cumulative hierarchy using definable powersets justifies the powerset axiom. On the other hand, there is no good justification of unbounded replacement and unbounded comprehension even without the powerset axiom, as far as I know.